# Urllib syntax translation from python 3.5 to 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I have a piece of code which was written in Python 3.5 and uses `urllib` module. Now, I tried to convert this so that it will work with Python 2.7, but I get some errors from the `urllib()` module.

E.g:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alert.py", line 13, in <module>
    import urllib.request as urllib
ImportError: No module named request
```

Now, I know that urllib is deprecated in Python 2.7 so I'm coming here to ask for some help with the lines that use urllib.

```
import urllib.request as urllib
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
from os.path import isfile
from os.path import join as joinPath
from sys import exc_info
from traceback import print_tb
from urllib.parse import urlencode

# constant
APPLICATION_PATH = '/srv/path/'
ALERT_POINT_PATH = joinPath(APPLICATION_PATH, 'alert_contact')
URL_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 42

SMS_BOX_URL = 'xx.xxxx.xxx.xxx'


def initWebConnection():  # init web connection
    response = 0
    initUrlLibResponse = initUrlLib()  # init urllib
    if initUrlLibResponse:
        response = 1

    return response


def initUrlLib():  # init urllib
    response = 0
    try:
        cookieJar = CookieJar()  # cookies
        opener = urllib.build_opener(urllib.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))
        urllib.install_opener(opener)
    except Exception as e:
        response = 1

    # ex_type, ex, tb = exc_info()
    return response


def urlRequest(url, data=None):  # make url request
    contentResponse = None
    try:
        request = None
        if data:
            dataRequest = urlencode(data)
            dataRequest = dataRequest.encode('UTF-8')
            request = urllib.Request(url, dataRequest)
        else:
            request = urllib.Request(url)
        response = urllib.urlopen(url=request, timeout=URL_REQUEST_TIMEOUT)  # make request

        # get response
        contentResponse = response.read()
    except Exception as e:
        contentResponse = None

    # ex_type, ex, tb = exc_info()
    return contentResponse


try:
    evt.data = 'Some name'

    # check production state
    isInProduction = False
    if evt.prodState == 1000:
        isInProduction = True

    if isInProduction:
        initWebConnection()

        # check alert point'
        if isfile(ALERT_POINT_PATH):
            alertContactContent = None
            with open(ALERT_POINT_PATH, 'r') as alertContactFile:
                alertContactContent = alertContactFile.read()
            alertContactContent = alertContactContent.splitlines()

            if alertContactContent:
                evt.summary = '#[ DNS:  ALERT ]#  {}'.format(evt.summary)

                for alertContactContentLine in alertContactContent:
                    webRequestData = dict(
                        ## TO DO: set the url parameters appropriately
                        phone=alertContactContentLine,
                        message='NEW ALERT: {}'.format(evt.ipAddress),
                    )
                    webRequestResponse = urlRequest(SMS_BOX_URL, webRequestData)
        else:
            evt.summary = '#[ ERROR: SMS ALERT NO CONTACT ]#  {}'.format(evt.summary)
except Exception as e:
    ex_type, ex, tb = exc_info()
    print('\n #[ERROR]#exception: {ex}\n'.format(ex=e))
    print('\n #[ERROR]#exception traceback: {trace}\n'.format(trace=print_tb(tb)))

    evt.summary = '#[ DNS:ERROR traceback in event message ]#  {}'.format(evt.summary)
    evt.message = '#[ DNS:ERROR ex_type:\n {} \nex: {} \n traceback:\n {} \n]#  {}'.format(ex_type, ex,
                                                                                                      print_tb(tb),
                                                                                                      evt.message)
```

Comment: Use `import urllib` instead.

Comment: @zondo, now it says no module named `http.cookiejar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the import lines from

```
import urllib.request as urllib
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
from urllib.parse import urlencode
```

to

```
import urllib2 as urllib
from cookielib import CookieJar
from urllib import urlencode
```

for Python 2.7

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk, but I still get the following error: ` from urllib.parse import urlencode ImportError: No module named parse`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'll accept this as it does what I asked for.